# Rearrange print order of key-value data read from file in Perl

Tags: perl

My data looks like:

```
"latDD":33.732867,
"lonDD":-84.404525,
"callsign":"AAL1300 ",
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:49.46Z",
"latDD":33.732867,
"lonDD":-84.404525,
"callsign":"AAL1300 ",
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.186Z",
"latDD":33.781071,
"lonDD":-84.401736,
"callsign":"GT017   ",
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.0Z",
"latDD":33.781071,
"lonDD":-84.401736,
"callsign":"GT017   ",
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.0Z",
"latDD":33.732867,
"lonDD":-84.401664,
"callsign":"AAL1300 ",
```

I want to print `callsign` first, then print the `latDD` that is before `callsign` second, then print the `lonDD` that is before `callsign` third,
then the `timeStamp` that is after `callsign` fourth.

the finished data should look like:

```
"callsign":"AAL1300 ",
"latDD":33.732867,
"lonDD":-84.404525,
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:49.46Z",
"callsign":"AAL1300 ",
"latDD":33.732867,
"lonDD":-84.404525,
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.186Z",
"callsign":"GT017   ",
"latDD":33.781071,
"lonDD":-84.401736,
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.0Z",
"callsign":"GT017   ",
"latDD":33.781071,
"lonDD":-84.401736,
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.0Z",
```

I've tried shifting the print statements around in the code but since the data is in a specific order, it seems to only want to print the data out in the order that it is originally in.

```
use strict;

my $find3 = "latDD";
my $find4 = "lonDD";
my $find1 = '"callsign"';
my $find2 = "timeStamp";

open (NEW1, ">", "new1.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";
open (FILE, "<", "test revam.txt") or die "could not open:$!";

while (<FILE>) {
    print NEW1 if (/$find1/);
    print NEW1 if (/$find2/);
    print NEW1 if (/$find3/);
    print NEW1 if (/$find4/);
}

close (FILE);
close (NEW1);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not clear on the transformation here--it looks like the last 3 lines were chopped off on the output. Where did they go?

Comment: It'd be easier if your data was an array of JSON objects. Did it start out as that by chance and something stripped out all the brackets and braces?

Comment: it does "start" as JSON but then it is picked up through "wireshark" where I get the "raw" data

Answer (score 2):

```
while (1) {
   defined( my $line1 = <> ) or last;
   defined( my $line2 = <> ) or die;
   defined( my $line3 = <> ) or die;
   defined( my $line4 = <> ) or die;

   print $line3, $line1, $line2, $line4;
}
```

Comment: not sure what I did wrong but...now it does not print anything...   use strict;

my $find1 = "latDD";
my $find2 = "lonDD";
my $find3 = '"callsign"';
my $find4 = "timeStamp";

open (NEW1, ">", "new1.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";
open (FILE, "<", "test revam.txt") or die "could not open:$!";

while (<FILE>) {
   defined( my $line1 = <$find1> ) or last;
   defined( my $line2 = <$find2> ) or die;
   defined( my $line3 = <$find3> ) or die;
   defined( my $line4 = <$find4> ) or die;

   print $line3, $line1, $line2, $line4;
}


close (FILE);
close (NEW1);

Comment: where in my code is you code suppose to sit? is there script/code that goes into <>?

Comment: You can specify a file handle. But if you don't, it will read from the file(s) passed as arguments to the script, or from STDIN if no arguments were provided. This is generally preferable to hardcoding the paths, but it's up to you

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of one set of your data (one of each of line) and then when you have a last line in the set (in this case timestamp) print them all in the order you prefer.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my %vals;   # hash to hold a set of lines

# read data (I'm using __DATA__, you probably want a file or stdin)
for my $line (<DATA>) {
    my ($key) = $line =~ /"(.+?)"/; # parse the key out of the line
    $vals{$key} = $line;        # save the line for this key
    if ($key eq 'timeStamp') {  # are we done with this set of lines?
        printBlock();   # print them
        %vals = ();     # clear the hash for the next set of lines
    }
}
printBlock();

sub printBlock {
    print '-'x50 . "\n";    # OPTIONAL print a line between each set
    print $vals{callsign};
    print $vals{latDD};
    print $vals{lonDD};
    print $vals{timeStamp};
}

__DATA__
"latDD":33.732867,
"lonDD":-84.404525,
"callsign":"AAL1300 ",
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:49.46Z",
"latDD":33.732867,
"lonDD":-84.404525,
"callsign":"AAL1300 ",
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.186Z",
"latDD":33.781071,
"lonDD":-84.401736,
"callsign":"GT017   ",
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.0Z",
"latDD":33.781071,
"lonDD":-84.401736,
"callsign":"GT017   ",
"timeStamp":"2019-07-19T13:47:50.0Z",
"latDD":33.732867,
"lonDD":-84.401664,
"callsign":"AAL1300 "
```

Comment: sir, say that my data is in a file named "NEW" how do I insert the file name into your code so that your code works?

Comment: Replace the 'for my $line ..." line with the following two lines:      
  
    open (IN, '< NEW') or die "Failed to open file $!";
    while (my $line = <IN>) {